# How can I receive OutputDebugString from a service?

Tags: c#, delphi, windows-services, remote-debugging, outputdebugstring

I'm trying to catch all [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages (including those from services) using the following code. It worked fine until I migrated to Windows 7.

The problem is that since Windows Vista services are running in the low level Session #0, some people say that [it's impossible](http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.nativeapi.win32/200711/0711019285.html) to catch them and some that it is. What do you think?

Is it possible to modify the following code by increasing some rights to be able to receive [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages from the Session #0? In other words; is it possible to share DBWIN_BUFFER in the session #0 with Session #1?

I would say it should be possible because e.g. DebugView can do that, and I can't see any service helper which would send those messages (e.g. through the named pipes) from the Session #0 to Session #1, where the GUI's running.

The problem will be IMO in the security settings. Can anyone suggest me how to modify them?

```
type
  TODSThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

...

procedure TODSThread.Execute;
var SharedMem: Pointer;
    SharedFile: THandle;
    WaitingResult: DWORD;
    SharedMessage: string;
    DataReadyEvent: THandle;
    BufferReadyEvent: THandle;
    SecurityAttributes: SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;
    SecurityDescriptor: SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;

begin
  SecurityAttributes.nLength := SizeOf(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
  SecurityAttributes.bInheritHandle := True;
  SecurityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor := @SecurityDescriptor;

  if not InitializeSecurityDescriptor(@SecurityDescriptor, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION) then
    Exit;

  if not SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(@SecurityDescriptor, True, nil, False) then
    Exit;

  BufferReadyEvent := CreateEvent(@SecurityAttributes, False, True, 'DBWIN_BUFFER_READY');

  if BufferReadyEvent = 0 then
    Exit;

  DataReadyEvent := CreateEvent(@SecurityAttributes, False, False, 'DBWIN_DATA_READY');

  if DataReadyEvent = 0 then
    Exit;

  SharedFile := CreateFileMapping(THandle(-1), @SecurityAttributes, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 4096, 'DBWIN_BUFFER');

  if SharedFile = 0 then
    Exit;

  SharedMem := MapViewOfFile(SharedFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 512);

  if not Assigned(SharedMem) then
    Exit;

  while (not Terminated) and (not Application.Terminated) do
    begin
      SetEvent(BufferReadyEvent);
      WaitingResult := WaitForSingleObject(DataReadyEvent, INFINITE);

      case WaitingResult of
        WAIT_TIMEOUT: Continue;
        WAIT_OBJECT_0:
          begin
            SharedMessage := String(PAnsiChar(SharedMem) + SizeOf(DWORD));
            // here I have what I need and process it in the main thread
          end;

       WAIT_FAILED: Continue;
     end;
   end;

   UnmapViewOfFile(SharedMem);
   CloseHandle(SharedFile);
end;
```

<sub>I've added the C# tag even if the code is in Delphi because the security attributes are common for the whole Windows API and C# has many followers :)</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Someone talked about the same issue in the [SysInternals forums](http://forum.sysinternals.com/outputdebugstring-and-session-0-in-vista_topic11040.html).  Their solution was to [add "Global\" to the named objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx).

So use the following

```
CreateEvent(@SecurityAttributes, False, True, 'Global\DBWIN_BUFFER_READY');
CreateEvent(@SecurityAttributes, False, False, 'Global\DBWIN_DATA_READY');
CreateFileMapping(THandle(-1), @SecurityAttributes, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 4096, 'Global\DBWIN_BUFFER');
```

Comment: +1 and accept. Thank you; works perfectly. I'll add the specific solution to your answer with excuse.